# Compute string as an arithmetic operation

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string which consists of numbers separated by either addition, subtraction, multiplication, division signs etc, eg:

`"1+2*3"="7"`.

The maximum number of signs can be two. I want to compute this string as an arithmetic operation. How can I do this? My current thinking is to split this string into a list then calculate the result using the normal order of arithmetic operation.

Comment: Will you please post what you have tried till now...

Comment: You really don't want that in a list. A simple and effective way to do what you're asking is with the Shunting Yard algorithm. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29634992/shunting-yard-validate-expression

Comment: you can use regular expression to catch numbers

for example `(\d)` is proper for you

please check below link 

https://regex101.com/r/kP9iX9/1

Comment: You say "Once I have this string into a list I can then calculate the result using the normal order of arithmetic", but no, you can't. You need to do the multiplication before the addition in your example. You need a tree structure to evaluate mathematical expressions.

Comment: So whoever downvoted for the answer can you please explain why?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the the built in [DataTable.Compute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.compute.aspx) method instead of coding it yourself :

```
var result = new DataTable().Compute("1+2*3", null); // Will result in 7
```

### Edit :

[DataTable do not implement Dispose method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/913286/6170636) so it is safe to use them that way. However it does not get uglier if you wrap them in a `using` statement. See a related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18796518/6170636).

Comment: Thank you @fabien. I will try this.

Comment: `DataTable` implements `IDisposable` so should not be used like this as you can't call `.Dispose()` after you're done. A reference must be take to dispose of.

Comment: @Enigmativity `DataTable` has no unmanaged ressource to Dispose, and it is actually do not implement it. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/913286/6170636

Answer (score 0):

I was able to take care of this issue without splitting the string into separate elements(and then applying the rules of arithmetic operations).

```
using System;
using System.Data;
 public int Maths(string operation)
        {
            object result=new DataTable().Compute(operation, null);
            return Int32.Parse(result.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: I undeleted my answer since I'm able to proove that it was not so bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the numerous parser generators. Most popular in .NET platfrom, I think, is Antlr.
Or, even, you can write parser from scratch using Pratt algorytm, it's pretty easy. Clear guide - http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/