# Shunting Yard Algorithm in case "a b +"

Tags: algorithm, shunting-yard

I'm learning shunting yard algorithm.
I've read wikipedia and it provided me with detailed
[steps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

But if you write the expression like **1 2 +** it will be evaluated in the same way as **1 + 2.**

Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: In particular, what's wrong with evaluating `1 2 +`?

Comment: It is not in infix notation. (When implementing mathematical expressions parser you want to be aware that input is incorrect)

Comment: Some [solutions have been presented before](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29634992/555045) but IMO if you're going to add significant parser tech you might as well use an actual parser

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen the solution. Sorry )

Comment: @George: right -- the shunt isn't an accept-reject parser.  It promises to properly evaluate legal expressions, but doesn't guarantee rejection of other input.